# How to open pdf file with in our app android+phonegap+JQM?

Tags: android, cordova, jquery-mobile, jquery-plugins

I am developing an web+cross platform app using Jquery Mobile+PhoneGap+Android. In web app, I am able to open pdf file links within my app page using iframe. But, in Phonegap generated Android build, iframe is unable to render pdf content,it is showing that iframe area as empty.How can I display the pdf file/content, whose src I know at runtime, within android webview. Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've just published my plugin, which can open almost any type of file, which is stored locally on Android device.

Please take a look at: https://github.com/markeeftb/FileOpener

Plugin opens external application which handles the preview of the document.

Comment: I have a phonegap app. But file is not stored locally,my pdf files are stored on AWS.amazon server, and I want  to open that in my phonegap app. is it possible to open that file using this plugin?

Comment: No, this plugin doesn't open remote files directly. However you could first download the file using file transfer plugin, store it on your device and then  open it using my plugin.

The file transfer plugin is available here: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer